# Behavior of classes in python

Tags: python-3.6

I am new to python but I uses some of the scripting langues like ( Shell, Perl, Powershell) for my day to day work. What most of the time, bothers me is the classes in general. I have some idea about classes but get confused if while analyzing the below code.

### Code:

```
my_var = "Hello"

class Test:
    my_var = "Hi"
    print("my_var from within the class : {}".format(my_var))
print("my_var from out side the class : {}".format(my_var))
```

---

### output:

```
my_var from within the class : Hi
my_var from out side the class : Hello
```

Q > Why does the statements inside the class gets executed without the class?

Answer (score 0):

A `class` code block is just like any other code block, where you can execute any statement a regular code block can, and the variables defined in a class code block would be local to the code block, which is why your use of `my_var` within the class definition would refer to the `my_var` class variable.

The only difference with the variables or functions defined inside the code block of a class is that they would become the attributes of the class, so that they are accessible elsewhere through the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.